# Serialize whole instance with child instances (class serialization) and save to file

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game with Unity3D. I have a class called GameInstance containing all the current game instance data in it. It contains multiple sub classes for instance the `Player` property would return a `Player` object.

Yet all objects are simple key/values objects, it's only data. Now I'd need to serialize all of this and save it to a file so I can reload it to restart the game where it left.

That's what I basically intent to do, maybe somebody would have a better suggestion but yet that's the most flexible option I found.

I used .NET XML object serialization in the past but it's been a while and I'd need to have a more direct advice on this. Should I serialize to XML or JSON for example?

**TL;DR**: I want to serialize a whole class with all its content with C#/.NET in a Unity3D project. How should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask? You say you've used XML and Json, presumably successfully. Based on that, what problem are you trying to solve? There are alternatives like protobuf-net, but whether or not that is a solution depends on what the problem is... (for reference, protobuf-net targets performance and size/bandwidth)

Comment: Oh it's just that I used these back some years ago with VB.NET so using it with C# looks a bit different. I'm just looking for the proper way of doing it with C# instead of hacking it myself the wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer json. If you're using json.NET this will be as simple as;

```
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
```

or to compact it;

```
   File.WriteAllText("./myfile", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject));
```

Then to deserialize you would just do;

```
   MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(File.ReadAllText("./myfile"));
```

EDIT: In response to the exception, you want to use this overload which allows you to change the serilization settings;

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResultGroups, 
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    { 
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
```

Comment: Really? I'm using json.NET already for something else but I thought what I asked was too complex for it. Damn I'll have to try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @TomShreds any complext object can be deserialized with that one liner in the bottom if you have an object who's definition is compatible with the json. Since you're doing both serialization and deserialization the json you output using the `SerializeObject` is guaranteed to deserialize back into an instance of that object with no problems.

Comment: Seems there's issues using it with Unity3d since there Vector2/3 instances bugs the thing: JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'normalized' with type 'UnityEngine.Vector3'. Path 'Employees[0].Position.normalized.normalized'. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @TomShreds yeah, you need to set `ReferenceLoopHandling` to the `Ignore` setting. It's throwing the exception because there's potential for infinite recursion. I'll update with the `SerializeObject` overload you want to call.

Comment: Oh crap it seems to break something in my game because once I serialize the thing, I get weird errors like: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Employee(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody to the game object "Employee(Clone)". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Comment: Anyways, it's still a great start. I'll try to fix these errors now :) Thanks!

Comment: @TomShreds yeah idk what those errors are but the serialization shouldn't change anything. It doesn't modify the object which you're serializing. I would look more into what other code might be getting executed as a result of the changes you've added.

Comment: Only when I comment out `var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GameInstance.Instance, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });` that error pops out. I think I assign a gameobject in that instance somewhere, it might freaks out Unity..

Comment: Are you aware of a way to ignore a certain property while serializing? That'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: @TomShreds if in the class you put `[ScriptIgnore]` above the property then I believe it will not be serialized.

Comment: It seems that this attribute isn't available in Unity. I'll do some research on how to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I stumbled upon that one: [JsonIgnore] in Newtonsoft.Json. I guess this is it :D